# "Think (noun)" in phrases meaning "Think of (noun)"/ "Like (noun)"

Tags: prepositions, verbs

There is a colloquial type of phrasing where *think* functions as an adverb, similar in meaning to *like*. Example:

> There have been people in history that overturned previous cultural paradigms. Think Nietzsche, Bloom, Lebowitz.

Is it okay to leave *of* after *think* here in writing? It looks colloquial but fine to me.

Comment: It's totally colloquial. It's still a verb, though.

Comment: It's a verb in an imperative clause, with "Nietzsche, Bloom, Lebowitz" as direct object..

Comment: In your context, prepositionless ***Think X, Y, Z*** means ***X, Y, and Z are examples*** (of whatever the preceding text is about). It's entirely a stylistic choice whether to include ***of*** there or not. But in something like *You can't keep bringing your drinking buddies home after a night down the pub! Think **of** the children!* you ***can't*** idiomatically omit the preposition.

Comment: @BillJ Is "think" a transitive verb here?

Comment: "Take" can be used similarly in a conversational style to introduce an example that will be used to elaborate a point: "Many recent presidents have been elected despite losing the popular vote. **Take** George W. Bush. In 2000, he won the Electoral College..." "Think" is a bit different because it does not require further elaboration of the example.